# How to search this pattern in vim?

Tags: regex, vim

```
/'text': '.+'
```

In VIM, I want to match up to 'abc' and 'a' from 'text' in two cases:

```
'text': 'abc', 'url': 'http...'
'text': 'a', 'title': 'dog'
```

I want to match at least one character in the single quote after the colon. This doesn't seem to work.

I got it. This worked!

```
/'brand': '[^']\+'
```

Comment: If there will be no commas inside the strings, then `/^[^,]*` is enough for what you need

Answer (score 6):

The reason this isn't working is because the `+` atom must be escaped to have a special meaning in vim's flavor of regex. Right now this means *anything followed by a literal plus*. But when escaped, it means *at least one, but as many as possible*. So you'd want this:

```
/'text': '.\+'
```

However, this creates a new problem. The `.+` will match as many characters as possible, including the single quotes. So it ends up matching

```
abc', 'url': 'http...'
```

Instead of

```
abc'
```

So you want to use the *non-greedy* equivalent of `+` which is `\{-1,}`. Try this:

```
/'text': '.\{-1,}'
```

Of course, you could also turn on the *magic* option and do this:

```
/\v'text': '.{-1,}'
```

A nice overview on vim regex can be found at [vimregex.com](http://vimregex.com/). I use it all the time.

Comment: But this also match " 'text': 'a' 'xyz' ". It will match up to xyz. I only want to match up to 'a'.

Comment: @user697911 OK, then why didn't you specify that in your question? What *exactly* do you want to match or not match? (and edit it into the main question please)

Comment: Please see it again. Thanks.

Comment: The new one match 'brand': '', which is bad. I want to ensure at least one character in the single quote ''.

Comment: @user697911 Sorry about that! Fixed now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148560/discussion-between-user697911-and-djmcmayhem).